# How to add formatter.xml file in Appcelerator studio?

Tags: ios, xml, formatter, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

Have formatter.xml file which has formatting standards. Need to plugin this file into Appcelerator Studio so that the formatting rules defined in the xml file is applied to the project.

Answer (score 0):

Appcelerator Studio -> Preferences -> Studio -> Formatter -> Click on Import button (3rd button) -> select XML file